# Elegant Solution avoiding Global Variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to find an elegant and still readable Way of getting rid of that global Var. But cannot find a way to do it. no jQuery please it should work without any imports.

```html
<script>
  var anzahlErg = 0; //<--- THIS ONE

  function ajax(f) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        f(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "ajax1.php", true); // SELECT COUNT(*)
    xhttp.send();
  }

  function anfang(response) {
    anzahlErg = response;
  }

  function nachher(response) {
    if (anzahlErg != 0 && response != anzahlErg) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

  window.onload = ajax(anfang);
  setInterval(function() {
    return ajax(nachher)
  }, 250); //Polling Interval
</script>
```

Comment: You can bind it to some html element as a data attribute, or even as an id, but I am not sure how elegant that is in your situation.

Comment: Any reason why you want to create your own request, and not use fetch? Also note that you are calling `ajax(anfag)` instead of attaching it to the onload event (so in essence it is a useless assignment)

Comment: Why are you trying to get rid of the global variable in the first place? What exactly is the code supposed to be doing?

Comment: Probably because Globals are considered harmful

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Because we should always try to avoid globals?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm not sure whether I'm looking at an instance variable that's pretending to be a global variable or an actual global variable. I suppose the point is moot.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 What aren't you sure about? The variable in question is clearly global.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Right - on second read the code makes more sense - the foreign language threw me off a bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do all that coding. You can already hide it from the global by just wrapping the value inside the eventhandler of the load function. Note this will not run, but at least I added a clearInterval after the first error. ;)

This sample also uses the built in [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) method, which works with promises and makes the code a lot more readable.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let results;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    fetch('ajax1.php', {
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(response => {
      let count = parseInt(response.text);
      if (results === undefined) {
        results = count;
        return;
      }
      if (results !== count) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.location.reload();
      }
    }).catch(() => clearInterval(interval));
  }, 250);
});
```

A few more things to note about your original code though. :)

```
window.onload = ajax(anfang);
```

This statement is useless, as it executes the function at once, so the assignment is useless, it could be written instead as:

```
window.onload = () => ajax(anfang);
```

Your `XMLHttpRequest` method is also a bit overly verbose, note that the [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#Parameters) parameter is optional and defaults to `true` so there is absolutely no reason to supply it as an argument.

Which would execute it after the window has loaded, or you could use the `addEventListener` as shown in the code above.

Also reloading it if the counts are different seems very resource heavy, wouldn't it be better to reload the data that now has changed?

Concerning the count function, what happens if in the polling interval, an item got added and deleted?

And a final point, if your polling page would throw an error, many errors would occur, considering to either warn the user that the polling didn't work, or to disable the polling so that the user doesn't keep on sending requests if it failed (maybe giving a manual button to refresh, or showing a message to the user that refreshing was disabled).

You could eventually also rewrite your code in the following way

```
function ajax() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      if (ajax.results === undefined) {
        ajax.results = this.responseText;
      } else if (ajax.results !== this.responseText) {
        document.location.reload();
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "ajax1.php"); // SELECT COUNT(*)
  xhttp.send();
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setInterval( ajax, 250 );
});
```

This uses the `ajax` function to store the data, as functions are also objects. So the first time it will load the data, it will set the original values, the next times, it will compare the `responseText` with the value previously saved as a property on the `ajax` function.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap all your code in an **[Immediate Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)**. This is called the **["module pattern"](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)** and is very common in JS because functions cause their own scope.

Next, this line:

```
window.onload = ajax(anfang);
```

Will actually run `ajax(anfang)` as soon as it is encountered and not wait for the `load` event. The way it is written, it says: "Run this function right now and whatever function it returns is what should be registered as the function to call when `window.load` happens." Instead, you need to wrap that in a function that, itself becomes the handler.

Additionally, you should be using `.addEventListener()` to register event handlers instead of object properties, such as `onload` or `.onreadystatechange`.

```
(function(){
  var anzahlErg = 0; //<--- THIS IS NOW LOCAL TO THE IIFE

  function ajax(f) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        f(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    xhttp.open("POST", "ajax1.php", true); // SELECT COUNT(*)
    xhttp.send();
  }

  function anfang(response) {
    anzahlErg = response;
  }

  function nachher(response) {
    if (anzahlErg != 0 && response != anzahlErg) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    ajax(anfang)
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    return ajax(nachher)
  }, 250); //Polling Interval
})();
```

Comment: actually, that `f` is his callback function, the code you wrote now doesn't work anymore ;) So it is not a miswritten if statement

Comment: @Icepickle Well, not really. You're right that it appears to be a function, but it's not his callback. It's called from with his callback. And, the way he's got it set up as an argument, it doesn't look like he's passing a function in.

Comment: It is an argument to the ajax function, also note that your IIFE is missing an `{ ` in front of the `var anzahlErg` and missing a closing `}` as well

Comment: @ScottMarcus In my opinion wrapping the *entire* code base in an IIFE is pretty pointless for this case. It may technically not be a *global* variable, but it is still a *"global"* variable. The Modal Pattern is meant for a subset of code, not the entire code base. Unless OP has more code they aren't showing us.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's one opinion. The potential impact of any identifier colliding with a similarly named one has been mitigated. And, I'm not sure where you got the idea that the module pattern is meant for a subset of code. It's meant for a module. Have you ever seen how JQuery is set up?

Comment: @ScottMarcus *"I'm not sure where you got the idea that the module pattern is meant for a subset of code."* - That's not an idea *"I got"*, that's how it is supposed to be used. If you think otherwise you need to review this pattern. Putting the **entire** code base into a *"module"* gains no benefit and is not the correct way to use that pattern.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The pattern is meant to "modularize" code. Therefore any self-contained unit of code (no matter how large) is correct for this pattern. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js

Comment: @ScottMarcus *"Modular programming is a software design technique that emphasizes **separating** the functionality of a program into independent, interchangeable modules, such that each contains everything necessary to execute only one aspect of the desired functionality.".* You can't modularize code if you don't modularize it. If I put a IIFE around that entire jQuery file I didn't further "modularize" that code because it was already a module in the first place.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek You are preaching to the choir. We are in agreement. I believe that the code that I've shown the IIFE around is a module of code. It deals with the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Others have changed your code dramatically and they are good solutions but I thought I'd introduce closures and how to use them in your situation.

```html
<script>
  function ajax(f) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        f(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "ajax1.php", true); // SELECT COUNT(*)
    xhttp.send();
  }

  function cachedPoll() {
    var anzahlErg = 0;
    return {
      anfang: function anfang(response) {
        anzahlErg = response;
      },
      nachher: function nachher(response) {
        if (anzahlErg != 0 && response != anzahlErg) {
          location.reload();
        }
      }
    };
  }

  var pollers = cachedPoll();
  window.onload = function() {
    ajax(pollers.anfang);
  };
  setInterval(function() {
    return ajax(pollers.nachher)
  }, 250); //Polling Interval
</script>
```

I also updated your `onload` handler to be wrapped in a function instead of assigning the return value to `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the property to your ajax function, but really the cleanest way would to use Scott Marcus's answer.

```
function ajax(f) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      f(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "ajax1.php", true); // SELECT COUNT(*)
  xhttp.send();
}
ajax.anzahlErg = 0; // This is now a property of the ajax object and not the window object

function anfang(response) {
  ajax.anzahlErg = response;
}

function nachher(response) {
  if (ajax.anzahlErg != 0 && response != ajax.anzahlErg) {
    location.reload();
  }
}

window.onload = ajax(anfang);
  setInterval(function() {
    return ajax(nachher)
}, 250); //Polling Interval
```